# how do I display the in views this hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

how do I display the in views this hash?

```
class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :credit_data
end
```

I got the hash, but I can't display it in views.

```
=> [#<Credit:0x00000005d49900
  id: 18,
  credit_data:
   {3000=>[{1=>492}, {2=>984}, {3=>1536}, {4=>2136}, {5=>2760}],
    4000=>[{1=>656}, {2=>1328}, {3=>2048}, {4=>2816}, {5=>3620}],
    5000=>[{1=>820}, {2=>1648}, {3=>2560}, {4=>3544}, {5=>4540}],
    ........
  created_at: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 14:22:59 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 14:22:59 UTC +00:00>]
```

Comment: For example use `JSON.pretty_generate(credit.credit_data)` if you want to see it in JSON format and it acceptable.

Comment: @maxd I get this error `only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed`

Comment: `your_data.first.credit_data.each do |key, value| key value end` you can loop like this. And again `3000`, `4000` are internally hashes so you can again loop for them. But how you want to show them in view, in what format like table or what?

Comment: How do you want to display it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try something like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <% credit_data.each do |k,v| %>
            <th><%= k %></th>
            <% v.each do |v1| %>
                <td><%= v1.values %></td> 
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
</table>
```